# How to find limits at infinity algebraically for $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

For example the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x}$
How do I find the limit as the function approaches infinity without graphing?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You manipulate it algebraically

Comment: I forgot to add the $\sqrt{x} $

Comment: Have a look at posts about similar problems, such as [Show that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\to0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/545704) (and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/545704) or [How can I find if the sequence $z_n = \sqrt{n+2} - \sqrt{n} $ converges or diverges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1247405). You can probably find a few other similar post by [searching in Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B1%7D-%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 10):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt x
&=& \dfrac{(\sqrt{x+2})^2 - (\sqrt x)^2}{\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt x} \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{\underbrace{\sqrt{x+2}}_\infty+\underbrace{\sqrt x}_\infty} \\
&\to& 0
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 4):

By the mean value theorem,
$f(x+c)-f(x)
=cf'(z)
$
where
$x \le z \le x+c$.

Therefore,
if $f'(x) \to 0$
as $x \to \infty$,
$f(x+c)-f(x)
\to 0$
for any fixed $c$.

If $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$,
$f'(x)
=\dfrac1{2\sqrt{x}}
\to 0
$
as $x \to \infty$.
Therefore
$\sqrt{x+c}-\sqrt{x}
\to 0
$
as $c \to \infty$.

Note that
the MVT
gives the bounds
$\dfrac{c}{2\sqrt{x}}
\ge \sqrt{x+c}-\sqrt{x}
\ge \dfrac{c}{2\sqrt{x+c}}
$.

Comment: nice! though it uses calculus, this is really pretty.

Answer (score 2):

$$
f(x)=\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{x} \left(\sqrt{x+2\over x} - 1 \right) =
\sqrt{x} \left(\sqrt{1+{2\over x}} - 1 \right)
$$
$$
=\sqrt{x} \left(1+{1\over x}+O\Big({1\over x^2}\Big) - 1 \right)
={1\over\sqrt{x}} + O\Big({1\over x^{3/2}}\Big) \ \to \ 0 \quad\mbox{ as }x\to\infty.
$$